# Quartz .net call scheduler outside of DI container or Main method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, quartz.net

We are trying to use quartz for some of our scheduled tasks such as email and record duplication. It seems to be a perfect fit however, the documentation hasn't really been updated for DI stuff and repo unit of work patterns so we have an issue. We have a separate project in our solution where we want to house our scheduler and different jobs, which will have access to our service layer where each Job calls our service. The issue is, we aren't sure how to get access to the scheduler after it gets instantiated in the job runner project's main file.

Main file:

```
  private static async Task Main(string[] args)
 {
   LogProvider.SetCurrentLogProvider(new ConsoleLogProvider());
   // Grab the Scheduler instance from the Factory
   StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
   IScheduler scheduler = await factory.GetScheduler();
   
// and start it off
   await scheduler.Start();
   
// and last shut down the scheduler when you are ready to close your program
   await scheduler.Shutdown();
}
```

Typical Job:

```
using Quartz;
using Compyl.AppLogic.AssessmentService;

namespace JobRunner.Jobs
{
    public class AssessmentDuplicationJob : IJob
    {
        private readonly IAssessmentService _assessmentService;
       
        public AssessmentDuplicationJob(IAssessmentService assessmentService)
        {
            _assessmentService = assessmentService;
          
        }

        public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            var dataMap = context.MergedJobDataMap;
            var id = dataMap.GetInt("id");
            var shouldPopulateAnswers = dataMap.GetBoolean("shouldPopulateAnswers");
            _assessmentService.DuplicateAssessment(id, shouldPopulateAnswers);
        }
    }
}
```

we want to have a class or method *in the job runner project* that houses the scheduler through DI and a method(s) like

```
[Inject] IScheduler scheduler
public ScheduleEntity (T entity)
{
   var job = createJob(entity)//another method that creates the job and jobdatamap this is easy enough
   var trigger = createTrigger(entity)// same as above
   scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger)

}

Then we would call the ScheduleEntity method wherever we needed it in our webapp.
```

Comment: Do you have a class for matching jobs ?Is it registered as a service ?

Comment: see below for our "solution"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the "correct" way, but what we're doing is setting up the default scheduler in the DI container and then using it in each component we need it by calling the factory's get scheduler method, and then using a static class from our other project to create and schedule jobs, using the scheduler as a parameter.